# Query string return null as string

Tags: javascript, laravel

I sent data from front to back, but when queries are null laravel return this one as string 'null'

**url:**
`url=example.com?name=null&phone=000000`

`$name=$request->input('name');` 
result : `name='null'`

**I can use** `$name=$request->input('name')==='null'? null :$request->input('name');`
**But I look for a cleaner solution**

Comment: `name=null` will send the string `'null'`... If you actually want `null`, then you need to do `name=` (blank, with no value)... `$request->input('name', null)` will handle it, but you need to adjust your query string.

Comment: In  `GET` method name will be converted into a string, this is normal

Answer (score 2):

Laravel already does have a few middlewares in place

> App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings - trims spaces from strings
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull - cases empty strings to null, ie "" will get converted to null.

When you deep-dig a little, Laravel internally has a built-in class to transform the incoming request, ie. *Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.

Now, you can create your own middleware to transform the incoming request.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middlewares;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest;

class CastStringifiedNullToNull extends TransformsRequest
{
    /**
     * Transform the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function transform($key, $value)
    {
        return is_string($value) && $value === 'null' ? null : $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for a cleaner solution:

```
$name = $request->input('name') ?? NULL;
```

I hope it is helpful.

Comment: in this case name always will retun 'null'

Comment: @milednassim How come ?. According to above code if your request input is null then only NULL would be assigned to it